# Could this be a cipher or not?

Tags: encryption, classical-cipher

I am trying to solve a puzzle, and I think have to solve a cipher. But I'm not actually sure what I have to do ... Example :

`The diu uff i dve. lleive pi he bl hle f he mi Nw ie d hiie d eve me Biie ide hi  i. Ti Bii imli  Vili Buei G Bii Ti imli, Gee li bei ipped el be  ie EL lvd ie Nvz d ell u h u.  lle Re Ve Bl ize W ee m) ull Sp. 5% hii fi d ld  ve deh he eul f Bii iible ue f ll vilble ee. hii The wme  mii bii f ue. The em f lve i ifiiel me effiie h he d w. di u ee umpi dp e ze beue u ul ede wd lve d pee e meized f he fi ime i u eiee. d hve bee livi i hee f 0 e. pp he i ll wih u`

Could you maybe share some ideas on how to solve it? There are many repeated sub-strings of characters like "imli", "lle", etc. One of the things I tried was to substitute "imli" for "that", since it is the only 4 character string without repeated characters and it begins and ends with the same letter. But I can't figure out the rest. Capitalization, punctuation and spaces may or may not be significant, I just don't know. Or maybe I'm way off with my puzzle and this is not even a cipher to try and decrypt.

Comment: Actually, that's not a cipher, that's Illuvatarian, the official language of the Federation of Arda ;)